# Camel : Can not findForFormattingOptions a suitable formatter for the type: java.util.List

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to convert pojo to csv in camel. Here is the model

```
 @CsvRecord(separator = ";")
 public class Model {
     @DataField(pos = 1)
     private String t;
     @DataField(pos = 2)
     private List<Integer> list;
 }
```

CSV that should get generated is A;1;2;3

I have defined a custom format factory for the same(list) in Camel. Here is the snippet

```
public class ListFormatFactory extends AbstractFormatFactory {

private final ListFormat listFormat = new ListFormat();

{
    supportedClasses.add(List.class);
    supportedClasses.add(ArrayList.class);
}

@Override
public Format<?> build(FormattingOptions formattingOptions) {
    return listFormat;
}

private static class ListFormat implements Format<List> {

    @Override
    public String format(List object) throws Exception {
        return Arrays.toString(object.toArray());
    }

    public List parse(String string) throws Exception {
        return Arrays.asList(string.split(";"));
    }

}
}
```

and I have registered this format factory using this

```
DefaultFactoryRegistry defaultFactoryRegistry = new DefaultFactoryRegistry();
    defaultFactoryRegistry.register(new ListFormatFactory());
```

But still I am getting the same error. Can some one help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind your defaultFactoryRegistry in the Jndi

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not findForFormattingOptions a suitable formatter for the type: java.lang.String
```

and that was caused by Camel not started properly. Restart of the application solved the problem. This is Quarkus application.